Lifting central units modulo Jacobson radical
Let $R$ be a finite unital ring (not commutative) and $J$ it's Jacobson radical. Assume that $R$ is local, that is, $R/J$ is a division ring and hence a finite field of characteristic $p$.
Since $Q = (R/J)^\times$ has order $p^k-1$ for some $k\geq 1$ and $1+J$ is a finite $p$-group, the Schur-Zassenhaus theorem tells us that $$R^\times = (1+J) \rtimes Q$$
The question is, can this product fail to be direct? I have no reason to believe it can't, but in all the examples I have the lifted units in $Q$ are actually central -- even more is true in those examples, the center $Z(R)$ is also a local ring and it's residue field is also $R/J$. One can also construct non-commutative complete local rings where central units don't lift to central units, but I don't know of a finite example where this phenomenon happens.

A commutative finite ring is a direct product of local rings, so $Z(R)$ is local.
The lifted units need not be central if $\log_p |R/J| > 1$. Here's an example (from A partial classification of local rings of order $p^6$): $R = \Bbb F_{p^3}[x;\sigma]/(x^2)$, where $\sigma$: $t \mapsto t^p$ is the Frobenius automorphism. Then $R/J \cong \Bbb F_{p^3}$ does not centralize $1+J$ (in particular, $x$).

Thanks for pointing out this example! A small modification can make it minimal among the rings with residual characteristic $p$. Indeed, writing $R/J \simeq \mathbb{F}_q$, we need $q > p$. Since $R$ has order $q^k$ for some $k \geq 1$, the least possible example would be a ring of order $p^4$. Such a ring can be found by taking the $\mathbb{F}_p$ algebra generated by two elements $a$ and $b$ satisfying (i) $a^2 = r$ if $p$ is odd and $r \not\in (\mathbb{F}_p^\times)^2$ or $a^2 = a + 1$ if $p = 2$, (ii) $ba = -ab$ if $p > 2$ and $ba = ab + b$ if $p =2$ and (iii) $b^2 = 0$.
